# Rerun axios.get in useEffect when url parameter changes

Tags: axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I have been learning React Hooks recently. I have researched for a few days to know how to fetch data and realized that there was `axios`.

I am using it to fetch data but the problem is it is not working properly when the parameter changes in the url. I have explored tonnes of posts related to this issue here but never got proper ideas.

Here is what I have tried so far. I simplified my code in the link: [MyCode](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-hw8rm?file=/src/index.js).

In my code, when a checkbox value changes, the axios fetches different data.

How can I rerun axios in useEffect when the url parameter changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rerun axios in useEffect when the url parameter changes?

Using a dependency

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://myURL/employee_id/${someParam}`).then((response) => {
      setEmployee(response.data);
    });
  }, [someParam]);
```

Although if I were you I would make the axios call inside `changeId` function directly. `useEffect` is overused sometimes. If you can make an action imperatively, there is no need to tie it to a variable and then track it also in `useEffect` for taking an action.

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughtful help!. I have tried ```[someParam]``` before. I got the infinite loop. I might have put the wrong variable.

Comment: @w4tw I didn't put `employeeId` because its usage seemed strange, you were copying `value` to it anyway...